# When I call two methods, one from the parent class and one from the child class, only the first call returns

Tags: python, object, methods, call

```
class Smarthphone():
    def __init__(self, tamanho, interface):
        self.tamanho = tamanho
        self.interface = interface
        
    def print_test(self):
        return "testing parent class"

class MP3Player(Smarthphone):
    def __init__(self, tamanho, interface, capacidade):
        super().__init__(tamanho, interface)
        self.capacidade = capacidade
        
    def print_MP3Player(self):
        return f"tamanho:{self.tamanho} interface:{self.interface} capacidade:{self.capacidade}"
        
        

ob1 = MP3Player(5, 'led', '240GB')

ob1.print_test()
ob1.print_MP3Player()
```

output:

```
'tamanho:5 interface:led capacidade:240GB'
```

If I swap the calls order the output would be  'testing parent class'.

Why does this happen?

Comment: They both return, you aren't doing anything with either of the return values. The output is *not* the output of this script, this script *doesnt' output anything*. this looks like you are running this in something like a Jupyter notebook or IPython REPL, which will *print the last value*, otherwise, you shouldn't *expect* anything to print

Comment: Got it. I'm using Jupyter notebook, I didn't know It prints only the last value. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't printing anything.  Whatever UI you are using is just showing you the last value the script produced.  Do it the right way:

```
print(ob1.print_test())
print(ob1.print_MP3Player())
```